# How to migrate AD domain groups in sharepoint 2010

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to migrate AD domain group "old\abc" to "new\abc"" domain in sharpeoint 2010 using powershell.

I am using powershell to run

```
stsadm -o migrategroup –oldlogin old\abc  –newlogin new\abc
```

but I want to know if there are any other better methods of doing it in sharpeoint 2010 as stsadm is used for 2007.

also please tell me how to run above command if AD group contains spaces between their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ready PowerShell script for migrating both users and groups when you have CSV of old and new account names is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2012/01/07/migrate-users-groups-powershell-script.aspx).

Save the following into Migrate.ps1 (or whatever).

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
function MigrateUserOrGroups($migrationType, $csvFile)
{
   #Getting the SPFarm object
   $farm = Get-SPFarm

   Write-Host $migrationType
   #Checking whether the user input the type of Migration as Group
   if($migrationType -eq "Group"){
   Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object{
      Write-Host "Migrating Group" $_.oldlogin "to" $_.newlogin -ForegroundColor Green
      $farm.MigrateGroup($_.oldlogin, $_.newlogin)

       }
      }

    #Checking whether the user input the type of Migration as User
    if($migrationType -eq "User")
      {

        Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object{
        Write-Host "Migrating User" $_.oldlogin "to" $_.newlogin -ForegroundColor Green
        $farm.MigrateUserAccount( $_.oldlogin, $_.newlogin, $false )
        }      
      }

   Write-Host "Migration Completed" -ForegroundColor Cyan


   # $farm.Name
}

MigrateUserOrGroups $args[0] $args[1]
```

CSV format

```
oldlogin,newlogin
oldad\account1,newad\account1
ad\account1,ad\account2
```

Call the .ps1 either `.\Migrate1.ps1 "User" .\users.csv` or `.\Migrate.ps1 "Group" .\groups.csv`

Comment: $farm.MigrateGroup($_.oldlogin, $_.newlogin) worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do a migration like this using PowerShell using the MigrateUserAccount and MigrateGroup method. SPFarm.MigrateUserAccount can be used in the same was as stsadm -o migrateuser.

Full syntax, once you've grabbed the farm object with Get-SPFarm and assigned an object $farm is:

- `$farm.MigrateGroup($oldlogin, $newlogin)`
- `$farm.MigrateUserAccount($oldlogin, $newlogin, $false)`

The boolean value on the MigrateUserAccount specifies whether or not to query AD and check the SID history. If $true it will confirm that the SID is the same for both accounts.

Also to run the stsadm command with spaces in names, simply surround the values with "", e.g. "My Domain\Old Username".